# minPadding doesn't work

Tags: highcharts

I have the [chart](http://jsfiddle.net/elias2012/b5Kkk/)

Now if data is equal 1 then the line is hard to see below image

[image]

I write:

```
minPadding: 0.08,
maxPadding: 0.08,
```

but this doesn't work

How to shift the graph down?

Comment: I don't know why downvotes, this question's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you you set `minPadding` to `0.08` you get the padding, but using `tickPositioner` starting on `1` it looks like not, because you need more space to show the padding.
So change it's start point from `1` to `0`.

```
tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
    return [0,10,20,30,40];
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtXSR/)

**Update** - According to the comment:

So set `startOnTick` to `false` and `min` to `0`, this will force to show the padding because the min is 0.

[**demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtXSR/1/) [**demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5Kkk/4/)

Comment: I need to get a 1 on the chart. Because I don't change it's start point from 1 to 0

Comment: @I.Zaytsev So take a look my update. This will fix this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `false` by default but it seems that if you explicitly set

```
startOnTick: false
```

Then you get the desired spacing:

[image]

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5Kkk/1/).

Comment: If I write startOnTick: false I lose fixed range: 
jsfiddle(I have not signed 1 near the yAxis and I have not fixed range): http://jsfiddle.net/elias2012/b5Kkk/3/
screenshot: http://regexinfo.ru/my_infa/parse_position/good/chart/4.jpg